# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 What WS-Trust version is supported in WSO2

Tags: wso2, delegation, ws-trust, actas

1. What WS-Trust version is supported in WSO2?
2. Does ActAs of WS-Trust 1.4 supported?
3. How can we login with delegation to our backend services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. WS-Trust 1.4 is supported by WSO2 Identity Server.
2. Yes.
3. Latest Sample STS client can be found at [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/5.0.0/modules/samples/sts/sts-client/). More details you can find from this [blog](http://dulanja.blogspot.com/2013/04/accessing-claim-aware-services-using_2.html)